# submitting a form using $.ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm calling this function when the dom is ready on `$().submit`
but it seems not working there is no response from server

```
$(function(){
     $("#logingform").submit(function(){

            var values =$(this).serialize();

            call_server("../php/login.php",values);
     });
});

function call_server(URL,DATA) 
{
    $.ajax(
        {
            type:'POST',
            url : URL,
            data : DATA,
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(response){
                    $("#d1").append(response);
                }
        }
        );
}
```

nothing seems to get back from the server.

```
server code
<?php

$email = $_POST['loginemail'];
$password =$_POST['loginpassword'];


echo json_encode(array('returned_val' => 'yoho'));
```

Comment: Do you get any error message ?

Comment: add an `error` handler...Look at the console for error messages.

Comment: btw try sending the json header from php "header("Content-Type: application/json", true);"

Comment: Remove the semicolon after `serialize`.

Comment: use $(this).serialize() removing ";"

Comment: Look at your error console, are there any errors. Look at your Net tab, do you see the request and response that you expect? Look at your server logs, does your server side code throw any errors?

Comment: @undefined nice catch with the semicolon ;)

Comment: After running `var values =$(this).serialize();`, please log the values and show us what it contains.

Comment: when alerting the values ,it gives the form filedsName=value.

Answer (score 1):

There is an extra semi colon following your ajax option:

```
data : $(this).serialize();,
```

vs correct

```
data : $(this).serialize(),
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to parse the json that is returned, since you already have `dataType:'json'` defined in the ajax options.

```
$("#d1").append($.parseJSON(response));
```

That is not necessary.

If you want to show the response object as a string, then you need to stringify it instead:

```
$("#d1").append(JSON.stringify(response));
```

---

Also, you have a syntax error on this line:

```
data : $(this).serialize();,
```

Remove the `;`.

---

Your data for a POST should be in json format, so rather than `$(this).serialize()`, use `$(this).serializeArray()` for your data. This will pass those values for POST body rather than in the querystring.

Comment: it's not the semicoln,or the json ,it still not work

Comment: You need to be a lot more specific than that! What errors do you get?

Comment: In your success method, do this first: `console.log(response)`. Anything there?

Comment: nothing i don't know what it's happeing, i tried befor with GET it worked fine but with post stoped.

Comment: I've updated the answer, try serializeArray rather than serialize.